# Как с помощью модуля `os` найти файл в загрузках, присвоить к переменной и парсить его?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На компьютере есть файл в загрузках (text.csv). Как мне с помощью модуля `os` его найти присвоить к переменной и парсить его? Может как то по-другому можно. Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом.

Answer (score 0):

Для открытия файла вам не нужен модуль `os`.

```
with open(r'...') as file:
           #/\ Путь до файла в формате C:\Users\user\Downloads\text.csv
    result = file.read()
```

`result` можно выводить через `print`, выполнять поиск по нему и пр. Помимо `read()` есть и другие методы. Поищите информацию про работу питона с файлами.

Для комфортной работы с форматом `.csv` есть специальные библиотеки, например `Python CSV` или `Pandas`. В интернете много информации и про них.